# AWS permissions required for sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a windows machine that need to sync a folder with S3.

I try

```
"C:\Program Files\amazon\AWSCLI\aws.exe" s3 sync components 
s3://test/MyTest/ --acl public-read --
cache-control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=1800"
```

got error *"A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied"*

**s3 rm** and **s3 cp** for the same directory works fine.

I have the following permissions :

```
"Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource":
```

Answer (score 49):

You need all this actions:

- `s3:DeleteObject`
- `s3:GetBucketLocation`
- `s3:GetObject`
- `s3:ListBucket`
- `s3:PutObject`

Not only `PutObject`, for get work S3 Sync, **use this policy**:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ],
            "Sid": "Stmt1464826210000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to add permission for the `s3:PutObjectAcl` action

Comment: I also needed to add `ListObjects` for sync

Comment: @robert-dundon There is no such `s3: ListObjects` action.. I think you are confusing IAM action with API action, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html

Comment: @YvesM. Ha! Yes, probably. In that case, I was using AWS CLI so that makes sense.

Also to note in that link, `ListObjectsV2` is recommended now.

Comment: Why would we need "s3:GetObject" and "s3:GetBucketLocation". I've setup our servers to backup to subfolders in a bucket and I've only given "s3:DeleteObject", "s3:ListBucket" and "s3:PutObject".

Comment: Curious, how would @JorgeM find out this information? Is there a place in the docs that references the APIs needed for this command to work completely (in most default cases).

Answer (score 7):

Synchronizing files also requires READ permissions because the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) needs to view the existing files to determine whether they already exist or have been modified.

Thus, you will also need to grant `ListBucket` permission.

If you use `aws s3 cp` instead of `aws s3 sync`, then this is not required.