# AccessDenied ListObjectsV2 although IAM/bucket policies are correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-iam

InI'm currently using Github Actions to deploy some files to s3. I keep getting a `fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied Error: Process completed with exit code 1.` despite having correct policies attached to the IAM user and S3 bucket.
AWS creds are being configured correctly and passing the github runner check.
MFA is not enabled for the IAM user.

**Running the command:**

```
aws s3 sync FILESPATH s3://BUCKET
```

**IAM Policy with S3FullAccess**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowBucketSync",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::USER"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You probably aren't actually using credentials associated that IAM policy. Check with `aws sts get-caller-identity`. And you don't need an S3 bucket policy if your IAM credentials have the [correct permissions for s3 sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894886/aws-permissions-required-for-sync).