# Unable to copy files from one S3 bucket to another using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using aws sync to copy files from Account B to Account A which is KMS key(aws/s3) encrypted while I copy I get the following error.

aws s3 sync s3://account-b/ s3://account-a/

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied`

Here are the following steps to enable cross account access, please do let me know what I am missing:

Account A:

1. Bucket policy of account-a

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Upload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345676890:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::account-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::account-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Created a role(kmss3bucket) and attached the below customer inline policy for kms key and opened up the trust relationship in that role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:9876543210:key/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345676890:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Account B:

1. Created a cross account policy and attached it to a role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::9876543210:role/kmss3bucket"
    }
}
```

2. This role again has a trust relationship for account-a

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9876543210:role/kmss3bucket"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How did you use the roles? For example, did you start with IAM User credentials from Account A or Account B? How did you assume any of the roles you listed? How have you granted access to read from the bucket in Account B? Under what IAM User / IAM Role did you run the `aws s3 sync` command?

Comment: The sync operation needs [additional actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894886/aws-permissions-required-for-sync) and the KMS key policy in account A must grant access to account B (note: key policy, not IAM policy, or trust relationship).